# destroy persistance from blackberry

Tags: blackberry, data-persistence

I use PersistentObject to store login and password to enter directly in the application
when I want to delete the values I use `PersistentStore.destroyPersistentObject(Info.KEY);`
But the values still exist. Should I add something?

Comment: @fou.. you want to delete the value in PersistentStore or the store itself ?

Comment: you getting any exception fro destroyPersistentObject() method call ?

Comment: no but I want when the user exit the application and return after showing the screen of login and password

Comment: paste the piece of code u using, that will help to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To destory the persistent object you should call PersistentStore.destroyPersistentObject(key) . It can throw ControlledAccessException if the caller does not have the permission to do it. Make sure you are calling the same key you are expecting to be deleted.